# Give customer the ability to save credit card using a credit card (saved) payment method

Tags: payment-methods, credit-card, magento1.9.0.1

I have a Magento store and a client used a credit card (saved) Magento's default payment method. Now the client wants the customer to have the ability to save their credit card details on the check-out step (using checkbox) for the next order. How can I save that detail and also use for next time when customer at the check-out step.

Magento version: 1. 9.0.1.

Comment: Yes, You Can save.

Comment: but how can I save can you give me explanation...

Comment: I would strongly advise not to save any credit card details into your own Magento store/database. It brings security risks and demands your store to be PCI compliant. Here's some official Magento documentation: https://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/payment/saved-cc.html

Comment: @7ochem Thanks for the useful comment. but then also client want to save credit card details then what should I do?

Comment: There's always the possibility to advice a client to not do something for very good reasons. That's also part of your job as a specialist. But how we look at credit cards differs per country/region. I'm from The Netherlands, there's tons of different payment methods here that are way better than credit cards...

Comment: You need to enable saved cc payment method and need customize in model of saved cc payment method.
I already worked on this.

Comment: so can you pls give me your model file? if yes please share your code as answer if possible